# django:OperationalError at /admin/login/ unable to open database file

Tags: python, django, windows, iis-6

I deploy my django project in iis6.When i login in the admin-page using the superuser name and password,it produce mistakes as follows:

```
enter code here
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in login
  413.         return login(request, **defaults)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in inner
  49.         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in login
  76.             auth_login(request, form.get_user())

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in login
  110.         request.session.cycle_key()

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in cycle_key
  305.         self.create()

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in create
  53.                 self.save(must_create=True)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in save
  86.                 obj.save(force_insert=must_create, using=using)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  708.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  736.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  820.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  859.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1060.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: unable to open database file
```

Here is my settings.py

```
enter code here
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\untitled5\\db\\db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

I tried to change the db file's privileges,but it just didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Use slashes instead of backslashes in the db file path [as is stated here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#name).

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/untitled5/db/db.sqlite',
    }
}  I change it like this,it still  not work